# chrome extension - issue with propertie "active" of chrome.tabs.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am **creating a new tab** and **and injecting some code** in it straight after.
But the problem is that the code to be injected is not injected properly when using the property `active:true`(which I need to use) on tabs.create.

Here is the code in popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://localhost:3000/", index: newTabId, active: false}, (newTab) => {
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // check status so that it sends only one message, and not one for each status change
    if(changeInfo.status === "loading") {
        if (tab.id === newTab.id) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(newTab.id, {message: "watch_video", videoData: selectedVideoData},
                function (resp) {
                    console.log("Resp",resp);
                    return true;
                }
            );
        } 
    }
 }); 
})
```

Here is the problematic line: `chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://localhost:3000/", index: newTabId, active: false}`. **When active is false**, the code is injected, **but when it is true**, nothing seems to happen.

inject.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.message === "watch_video") {
        console.log("inject soon")
        injectScript(request.videoData);
        sendResponse("watch_video script is to be injected in " + window.location.href)
    }
});

function injectScript(videoData) {
        console.log("injected")
        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.test = "ABCDE"
            const checkState = setInterval(() => {
                $(".bkg").css({ "background-color": "#ffffff"})
            }, 100)
        })
}
```

Here I tried something with `setInterval()`, it does not work w**hen active is true**.
However it does work with a `timeout`. But *does not not work without any timeout or interval* **when active is set to true**.

I could use just use a `timeout`, but it is not really clean, I would prefer to understand why it behaves like it does. I am using react btw.

Here is what it is said about the **active property**:

> Whether the tab should become the active tab in the window. Does not affect whether the window is focused (see windows.update). Defaults to true.
>   Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create

Comment: When a tab is opened in the foreground (active:true), the popup page is automatically closed, meaning its execution environment is destroyed and your callbacks won't run. You need to send a message to your [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) so it does everything like opening the tab and injecting the scripts.